# Stored Procedure with output parameters connected to method in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

Do you see something **blatantly** wrong with this line:

```
commaSepString1 = com.Parameters["@CommaSepString"].Value.ToString();
```

It shows an error like:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**For short, the C# method looks like:**

```
public static DataTable GetFilmDetails(string filmId, out string
commaSepString1)
```

It takes the following stored procedure (that executes correctly on its own):

```
com.CommandText = "CatalogGetFilmDetails2";
```

And since **@CommaSepString is an output parameter in the stored procedure**, in C# I have this:

```
param = com.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@CommaSepString";
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param.DbType = DbType.String;
com.Parameters.Add(param);

commaSepString1 = com.Parameters["@CommaSepString"].Value.ToString();
```

If you are curious about the Stored Procedure, it starts like this:
CREATE PROCEDURE CatalogGetFilmDetails2

```
(@FilmID int, @CommaSepString VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT) AS
```

The SP inserts some rows into a table variable based on some joins, it puts all values from column x from that table into a string with comma separated values:

> ```
> SELECT @CommaSepString 
> = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Categ  FROM @Filme1 FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')
> ```

then it selects the table.

Thank you for the patience to read this. Would it be more clear if I published the entire code for the stored procedure and the C# method? Not sure if I am allowed that and worried it might be too lengthy to read.

PS: There must be **something wrong about the commaSepString! The code worked perfectly before I added it in both places.**

Comment: At what point are you actually calling the stored procedure?

Comment: My question is the same as the one posed by Michael.  Your code snippet doesn't show the stored procedure being invoked.  Since the parameter is designated as output, the value would not be set without invoking the sproc, leaving it as null. Your null reference is likely due to the attempt to call the ToString method on the parameter's value.

Comment: The code doesn't expect to get a database NULL back.  `commaSepString1 = com.Parameters["@CommaSepString"].Value == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)(com.Parameters["@CommaSepString"].Value);`

Comment: Thanks everyone, the order was faulty indeed just as you said. Now I have another error: String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a breakpoint on the offending line, then you should examine your parameters collection to check if the parameter exists.
If it exists, then check if its value is null.
In this case the `.ToString()` will give you the error described.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was ridiculously using the output parameter before executing the stored procedure. I just fixed the order but now I get another error: **String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.**  I think this might just be due to the Stored Procedure not returning any result for that parameter? How can I check on the stored procedure on its own?

Comment: Add a `param.Size = 100;` or what do you expect is the length of the string returned, also be sure to update the stored procedure setting to the same size `nvarchar(100)`. [MSDN Refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx)

Comment: Goodness, it works! I'd never have thought of such a solution. It's first time I encounter this expression: **param.Size**. I will remember it. Thank you gazillions, Steve!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't know `output`, it only knows `input/output`.  So when you specify

```
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

SQL Server will actually read the string as well.  Since you haven't supplied a value, SQL Server determines that that its length is zero.

Incredibly, if you specify the magic number `-1`, SQL Server will determine the size for you:

```
param.Size = -1;
```

This is perhaps the second worst gotcha about ADO.NET.
Just behind the fact that SQL `NULL` translates to `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.